# Using NSString with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a problem with AVAudioPlayer to reach a sound from an other view. It's work perfectly with AudioToolbox but not with AVAudioPlayer. Here is my code :

.h file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>
#import "SimpleTableCelldetail.h"

int clicked;


@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {

AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
IBOutlet UIButton *start;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *audioSon;

@end
```

.m file

```
-(IBAction)play:(id)sender {

if(clicked == 0) {
    clicked = 1;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:audioSon, [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

    [audioPlayer play];
    [start setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else {
    clicked = 0;
    [audioPlayer stop];
    [start setTitle:@"Ecouter" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
}
```

When i run this code, the button don't play any sound.
The value of audioSon is "sound01.m4r".

When i replace the line

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:audioSon, [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
```

with

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/sound01.m4r", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
```

It works but xcode show me an error :

```
2012-08-01 01:59:44.697 CustomTable[12709:3703] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `stringWithFormat` in your original line when you should be using `stringByAppendingPathComponent`. If you change this you'll be accessing the correct file and your program should work.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:audioSon];
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks Dustin. There is just the error in Xcode still here.. But it could wait!